# How can I produce a mapping of each element to the number of times it occurs?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a defined list as `list =["a","b","d","f","g","a","g","d","a","d"]` and I want a dictionary like this `dicc = {a:2, b:1, d:3, f:1, g:2}`. The values in this dictionary are the number of times that the element of the list is repeated in the list. I tried the folowing but I dont know what to put in the `#`.

```
dicc = dict(zip(list,[# for x in range(#c.,len(list))]))


lista = ["a","b","d","f","g","a","g","d","a","d"]
dicc = dict(zip(list,[# for x in range(#c.,len(list))]))
print dicc 
dicc = {a:2, b:1, d:3, f:1, g:2}
```

Comment: Please consider to improve your code example. I find it very hard to understand what you were thinking when you wrote the code.
Also note that Python has a `Counter` data structure to solve this: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class does.

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(lista)
=> Counter({'d': 3, 'a': 3, 'g': 2, 'b': 1, 'f': 1})
```

`Counter` is a subclass of `dict` so you can use it as a dict.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use len(list) in case as python is very flexible and you have count() for lists.

Solution:

```
lista = ["a","b","d","f","g","a","g","d","a","d"]
dicc = dict(zip(list,[list.count(x) for x in list]))
print dicc 
>>>dicc = {a:2, b:1, d:3, f:1, g:2}
```

Or you can use Counter as mentioned in the comment. I will include the [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) where a similar example is given. In case you just have to call

```
dicc = dict(Counter(list))
```

This is because:

```
type(Counter(list)) -> collections.Counter
```

Still if you want the code as you have given you can use the below code. But its not the best way.

```
dicc = dict(zip(list,[list.count(list[x]) for x in range(len(list))]))
```

Both the solutions are same, first one shows the beauty of python. Hope you got your answer.